# Acumatica - Attachments File Extension Filter

Tags: acumatica

Good Day!
I am uploading some files in form as attachments and I am trying to filter the uploaded file extensions. But I am not getting the exact solution for this.
Is there any way to filter the extensions of the files being uploaded in file attachments?

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean blocking file upload based on the extension you can do so in `File Upload Preference Screen` (SM202550):

[image]

If you mean the filter for the native open file dialog. It seems hardcoded for a handful of common web files and I don't think it can be changed  easily.
[image]

If you mean the file upload dialog grid, unlike most grids in the system it is not filterable through the column headers:
[image]

Maybe the `Search in Files` page (SM202520) is what you're looking for. You can search files based on extension here:
[image]

Comment: Thank you sir, I would like to ask another question, Is there a way for me to filter a specific file extension on a specific screen id in attachments?

Comment: I'm still unsure about what you want to filter precisely. Is it a grid? a pop-up window?

Comment: Think I get it, you want the extension restriction configuration in File Upload Preference to be applied per screen. It is not supported out of the box. Given that requirement, as a workaround I would suggest creating a customization that retro-actively deletes the file after they have been updated. If events like RowUpdated are reliably called when file is uploaded you can hook them check the file, delete it and throw an exception error message to the user. For smallish files user won't really notice that it did indeed transfer.

Comment: The requirement is not a bad idea and I can see it being useful. If you mind you can suggest it for future development at: feedback.acumatica.com

Comment: I see. Thank you so much sir.